# Can't import component

Tags: react-native

The error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

class Logout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>Logout</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

export default Logout;
```

I am trying to import it in another file but the error above occur. This is how I import it:

```
import Logout from "../components/Logout";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please double check if **"react-native-gesture-handler"** library has **Text**
>   component. you might have mistakenly **import {Text} from
>   "react-native-gesture-handler"**. try:

```
import {Text} from 'react-native';
```